# Reverse legend histogram palette in tmap

Tags: r, histogram, tmap

I'm trying to plot the histogram values with the same order as the color palette of a raster legend, passing the parameter `legend.col.reverse = TRUE` reverses the legend but not the histogram, since I'm trying to plot elevation values, it's desirable to put highest on top of the legend.

**EDIT**

I can achieve it by plotting the layer twice and passing alternately the legend and histogram, but that's hacky.

```r
library(tmap)
data("land")
tm_shape(land, ylim = c(14,30), xlim = c(-105, -90)) +
  tm_raster("trees", palette = "Greens", title = "Percent Tree Cover", legend.reverse = T,
            legend.hist = T) +
  tm_layout(legend.bg.color = "white")
```

[image]

Comment: The histogram should remain the same when `legend.reverse` changes. I see that this is not the case: in your example light green should correspond to the tallest bar in the histogram. Is this what you mean?

Comment: yes, the tallest bar should be light green, but passing the `tm_raster` argument twice, one shape without the histogram and the reversed legend, and the other shape without the legend did the work. tmap is my most used package for plotting geospatial data in R.

Comment: I think this is an issue with tmap. I created an issue here: https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/546

Comment: It should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can't wait to use i!